# Nested multilevel model notation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, notation

I am fitting the following logit model in lme4 (R):

`dummy ~ individual_level_var1 + state_level_var2 + country_level_var3 + (1 | country/state)`

The model is fitted to data where individuals are in states which are nested in countries, so individuals/states/countries.
The model specifies varying intercepts for countries and states, with states implicitly nested within countries. I want to represent this model with its 3 levels displayed in the equation am using the following notation:

$\begin{align*}
logit(p(y_{ijk} = 1)) =
\pi_{0jk} +
\pi_{1jk} \cdot X_{ijk} +
\epsilon_{1jk}
\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
\pi_{0jk} =
\beta_{00k} +
\beta_{01k} \cdot X_{0jk} +
\omega_{1jk}
\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
\beta_{00k} =
\gamma_{000} +
\gamma_{001} \cdot  X_{00k} +
\upsilon_{00k}
\end{align*}$

Where -

- $\pi_{ojk}$ is the individual intercept, $\beta_{00k}$ is the state intercept, and $\gamma_{000}$ is the country intercept
- $\pi_{1jk}$, $\beta_{01k}$, and $\gamma_{001}$ are vectors of individual, state, and country-level coefficients
- $\epsilon$ is the individual level error, $\omega$ is the state error, and $\upsilon$ is the country error

However, this seems wrong to me - does the level 2 state intercept nest that way within the level one intercept? Is this correct? Is there a better way to write it? Thanks!

Comment: This is similar to another question I asked, but notice it is not the same - this is a different type of notation so I created a new question.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. The site supports mathjax formatting which means it is very good at rendering $\LaTeX$

Comment: Fixed by adding the Tex code. Sorry and thanks.